# Set theory question on ordering and Least upper bounds.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$c$ belongs to $\Bbb R$, $A$, $B$ are sets which belong to $\Bbb R$, and are bounded. How to prove the following?
$1$. if $A$ belongs to $B$ then lub$(B)>=$lub$(A)$
$2$. lub $(A\cup B)$ = maximum $\{$lub$(A)$, lub$(B)\}$
$3$. lub$(A\cap B)$ = minimum $\{$lub$(A)$, lub$(B)\}$ (is this even true)

Answer (score 0):

Consider $A=\{0,2\}$ and $B = \{0,3\}$ for the intersection.

The proof for the maximum and the union is straightforward from the definitions.

$A \subseteq B$ then $\sup(A) \le \sup(B)$ is likewise clear: an upperbound for $B$, e.g. $\sup(B)$, is one for $A$ too, and $\sup(A)$ is the minimal such upperbound. (your lub I changed to the more international $\sup$..)